# Improve functionality of react radio button group - allow multi-buttons clicked, and changes to numbers

Tags: javascript, reactjs

First, here is a reproducible example to work with, which simply draws a scatterplot with ~20 points included, and also has a radio button group with 3 buttons:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) { 
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      top10: "All"
    }
  } 
    
  handleTop10Change = (event) => {
        this.setState({ top10: event.target.value });
    };
      
  drawPoints() {
    const { top10 } = this.state;
    
    let myData = [
      { x1:30, y1: 50 },
      { x1:50, y1: 60 },
      { x1:70, y1: 70 },
      { x1:90, y1: 100 },
      { x1:110, y1: 150 },
      { x1:130, y1: 50 },
      { x1:150, y1: 180 },
      { x1:170, y1: 110 },
      { x1:190, y1: 130 },
      { x1:210, y1: 160 },
      { x1:230, y1: 50 },
      { x1:250, y1: 90 },
      { x1:270, y1: 40 },
      { x1:290, y1: 170 },
      { x1:310, y1: 230 },
      { x1:330, y1: 100 },
      { x1:350, y1: 200 }
    ];
    
    if(top10 === "10x") { 
      myData.sort((v1, v2) => v2.x1 - v1.x1)
      myData = myData.slice(0,10)
    } 
    if(top10 === "10y") {
      myData.sort((v1, v2) => v2.y1 - v1.y1)
      myData = myData.slice(0,10)
    }
    
     
    const pointsLayer = d3.select('#my-svg').select('g.points')

  pointsLayer
   .selectAll("circle")
   .data(myData)
   .exit()
   .transition()
    .duration(100)
    .attr('r', 0)
   .remove();

  pointsLayer
   .selectAll("circle")
   .data(myData)
   .enter()
   .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", d => d.x1)
    .attr("cy", d => d.y1)
        .attr("r", 10)

    pointsLayer
   .selectAll("circle")
   .data(myData)
   .transition()
   .duration(1000)
   .delay((d, i) => i * 0.5)
    .attr("cx", d => d.x1)
    .attr("cy", d => d.y1)
        .attr("r", 10)
  } 
      
  componentDidMount() {
    d3.select('#my-svg')
   .attr('width', '100%')
   .attr('height', '100%')
   .attr('viewBox', "0 0 " + (800) + " " + 600)  
   .attr('preserveAspectRatio', "xMaxYMax")  
  
    this.drawPoints();
  }
  
  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.drawPoints()
  }
  
  render() {
  
    const { top10 } = this.state;
    const top10Options = [
      { value: "10x", label: "Top 10 X" },
      { value: "10y", label: "Top 10 Y" },
      { value: "All", label: "All Guys" }];
    const top10Buttons = 
      <form>
          <div>
              {top10Options.map((d, i) => {
                  return (
                      <label key={'top10-' + i}>
                          <input
                              type={"radio"}
                              value={top10Options[i].value}
                              checked={top10 === top10Options[i].value}
                              onChange={this.handleTop10Change}
                          />
                          <span>{top10Options[i].label}</span>
                      </label>
                  )
              })}
          </div>
      </form>; 

    return(
      <div>
        
        {top10Buttons}
        <svg id="my-svg">
          <g className="points" />
        </svg>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>


<div id='root'>
  Come On Work!
</div>
```

Currently, only one option can be selected at a time. Selecting the `Top 10 X` option filters to include only the 10 scatter markers with the largest X values, and vice versa for the `Top 10 Y` option. I am seeking this functionality:

- both Top 10 X AND Top 10 Y could be clicked at the same time, although the All Guys option, when clicked, should unclick both other options.
- I would like it if the user could change the value `10` to the value of their choice, so that the scatter plot filters based on the number selected. Whether this is a text field that accepts numbers, or a number sliding scale, (not a select dropdown of numbers though), I don't have a preference as long as changing numbers is easy for the user.

I'm not sure how easy or difficult it is to tie both of the functionalities together into a single radio button group, but having it would be nice. As always, any and all help with this is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1) Use `type={"radio"}` instead of `radio` to make both Top 10 X and Top 10 Y able to be clicked at the same time. And store this data in state.

2) In `handleTop10Change` you can check, if one of them is already clicked. If it is, change the All Guys value.

3) If to update `value 10` each time, the user changes it's value (`<input onChange={handleChange}`>), the component will re-render with new data.